# Why can't I open a SQL Server CE database read-only when the SDF file has permissions that allow read-only?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I'm trying to open a `.SDF` file using SQL Server CE 4.0 SP1. The `.SDF` file lives in `C:\Program Files (x86)`. The permissions are set up so that normal users have read & execute permissions on the file. The client program is running as a regular user and tries to open the `.SDF` using this connection string:

```
"Data Source='{path-to-database-file}'; Password='{password}'; Max Database Size=4000;Mode=Read Only;Temp Path={users-temp-path};"
```

Opening a connection using that connection string results in

> Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region

The same code, when run as administrator, works perfectly.

If I add Modify & Write for all Users, it works perfectly as a regular user.

If I move the file to an app data folder, it works perfectly for that regular user.

Based on this evidence it looks like SQL Server CE cannot open a file for read only without the ability to write to the file.

Based on customer requirements nothing in `C:\Program Files (x86)` can be writable to regular users and all regular users need read-only access to the file.

What's up? What am I missing? Is this just not possible?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a windows file sharing issue.  Windows isn't allowing two people to access file.

Comment: Wonder if it is a platform move issue - see http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/08/running-sql-compact-from-cd-rom-read.html ?

Comment: Thanks for the response @ErikEJ.  I've been to the link that you referenced, and thought that this was so similar to the case that we have, but I was never able to get the index rebuild (due to the platform change, or language change,, etc.) to happen without opening the file for read-write.

Comment: You cannot get the index rebuild to happen without opening for read-write, the trick is to avoid the need for it to happen at all.

Comment: Thanks again @ErikEJ... Before we try to open the file read only from an application running under a normal user, we have a system service running under admin to open the file for read-write.  This is supposed to insure that any normal user applications will not have to rebuild the indexes.  We can see that the indexes are being rebuilt by the service, yet a normal user is unable to open the re-indexed file for read only.